# Mobile subdomain in app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mobile, subdomain

Can someone give me a basic rundown of how to set up a mobile site on app engine.  I already have a standard site set up but I want to use the same data store to run a mobile site.

I would like to redirect mobile users to m.mydomain.com.  Basically both sites will be the same I just want to show them different jsp pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing specific to App Engine here. All you need to do is detect the appropriate user-agents and send a redirect if you detect a mobile one. Then, map the mobile domain to your same application, and detect it in your configuration when determining what template to serve.

From a usability point of view, though, there's no need to direct users to a different subdomain - just serve the mobile version off the current domain. You should also always provide a way for users to override your autodetection and switch between mobile and regular versions, because it's impossible to keep up with every device out there.

Comment: So how do I make every call to m.mydomain.com/home pull up war/mobile/home.jsp

Comment: @Lumpy Use a servlet to serve your site, and have it determine which jsp to call out to based on whatever criteria you want. Or equivalently, use a filter to rewrite requests.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use server side logic to detect the user agent and render a desktop or mobile template, you will not be able to take advantage of edge caching (cache-control public). Edge caching is creates HUGE gains for high traffic sites, so it would be a shame. If you need it you may be better of re-directing with JavaScript.